# How can I restore Ubuntu's original splash text on startup?

Tags: login, kde, startup

A while ago I installed kubuntu-desktop to try out Plasma, didn't like it, and deleted it. I notice though that when I start the computer up the splash screen still says "Kubuntu". When I'm on the login screen for more than about ten seconds, the screen goes completely blank. This isn't much of a problem because I can still type my password and login and the display returns to normal when I do, but it's an annoyance.

Edit: Also I tried

```
sudo update-alternatives --config default.plymouth
```

and I selected the ubuntu-logo.plymouth, but it had no effect.

Comment: Maybe it requires `sudo update-initramfs -u` to take effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
sudo apt-get purge plymouth-theme-kubuntu-*
sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo
```

Comment: From the question it seems like OP has `plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo` installed. Maybe it's better to change the command to `sudo apt-get install --reinstall plymouth-theme-ubuntu-logo`

Comment: Yup that worked to fix the splash text itself, but the login screen still randomly goes dark after a few seconds. Any tips on that?

Comment: What display manager are you using? I guess it's `lightdm`. Can you try some other DM?